# What is Python List Comprehension of this Nested Loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have case like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
y = [[0 for i in xrange(size_of_array)] for j in xrange(size_of_array)]

offset_flag = 0

for i in xrange(size_of_array):
    for j in xrange(size_of_array):
        y[i][j] = starting_no + j + offset_flag
    offset_flag += j + 1
```

I want list comprehension of nested for loop but also it should handle case like follows:

```
offset_flag += j + 1
```

How can I achieve this kind of list comprehension ?

Comment: The list comprehension for this won't be nearly as readable as your current approach, considering the `offset_flag` update

Comment: Also, a list comprehension doesn't necessarily mean faster code

Comment: `[[starting_no + j + (i * size_of_array) + i for j in xrange(size_of_array)] for i in xrange(size_of_array)]` note that `j+1` is always `size_of_array`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: I think you have an off-by-one error, which is one reason I don't like using indices for stuff like this.

Comment: Analyse your loop; read the docs for (*nested*) list comprehensions; keep trying over and over till you work it out.

Comment: Your `j` is always going to be `size_of_array - 1` after the inner loop, so you are basically creating a value that could just be calculated with `i * size_of_array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire code could be replaced with:

```
# Changing variables for cleaner expression:
#    size_of_array -> s_a
#    starting_no -> start

y = [[start + j + (i*s_a) for j in xrange(s_a)] for i in xrange(s_a)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use multiplication instead to calculate your offset:

```
y = [[starting_no + j + (i * size_of_array) for j in xrange(size_of_array)]
     for i in xrange(size_of_array)]
```

which can be written a little more concisely using shorter variable names:

```
start, size = starting_no, size_of_array
y = [[start + j + (i * size) for j in xrange(size)] for i in xrange(size)]
```

Your `offset` value is nothing more than `i * size_of_array` here; each iteration of the outer loop you add `j + 1`, but `j` is *always* going to be set to `size_of_array - 1`. Substitute `j` for `size_of_array - 1` and you get `offset += size_of_array`. The first iteration it is `0`, then `1 * size_of_array`, all the way up to `(size_of_array - 1) * size_of_array`, following the `i` variable.